# C++ code while returning reference to integer

Tags: c++, reference

I tried the following piece of code:

```
int& fun()
{
    static int y = 20;
    //y = 40;
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If, line `y = 40` were uncommented, output of main is `40`. Why doesn't the value of `y` change when it's assigned to `30` in `main()` ?

Comment: Step through with a debugger and it should become clear.

Comment: By that logic, even without y = 40, wouldn't fun() reset y to 20 ?

Comment: @user4728046 because the static is initialized only once

Comment: @Christophe thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `y` of the function func() has **`static`** storage duration:

> **3.7.1/1:** All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have static
>   storage duration. The storage for these entities shall last for the
>   duration of the program
>
> **3.7.1/3:** The keyword static can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration.

The initialisation of such variables occurs only once.  This means that the first time you use `y` its value is 20, afterwards it keeps the value that you store there in.

**Case 1:  assignment is commented out:**

The statement `fun() = 30;` will store 30 in y.  `cout << fun()` will use the reference to y without `fun()` changing it, so it will display 30.

**Case 2:  assignment is activated:**

The statement `fun() = 30;` will store 30 in y.  `cout << fun()` will use the reference to y but `fun()` will first set it to 40, so 40 will be displayed.